# Array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, plot, sequence

want to plot x_values_edited and speed. I have this error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

```
plt.plot(x_values_edited, speed, '.' )
```

---

My code and inputs are here:

---

x_values_Edited:

[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 2), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 3), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 4), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 5), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 6), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 7), datetime.datetime(2015,

speed:

[[58.5, 97.0, 56.0, 87.5, 95.0, 100.0, 104.0, 98.5, 101.0, 98.5, 86.5, 90.0, 97.5, 16.5, 103.0, 98.0, 48.0, 98.5, 93.5, 99.0, 101.5, 86.5, 108.5, 22.0, 92.5, 84.5, 103.5, 86.5, 103.0, 96.5, 91.5, 101.5, 86.0], [99.5, 101.0, 96.5, 94.5, 92.0, 89.5, 83.0, 94.0, 97.5, 103.5, 93.5, 101.0, 95.5, 89.0, 102.5, 89.0, 104.5, 102.0, 107.0, 96.5, 97.5, 97.5, 93.0, 95.0, 88.5, 89.0, 101.0, 97.0, 98.5,  ]]

Comment: Why do you have double brackets around your speed?

Comment: You either have to put a working subset of your data or all of it. Right now the `.....` at the end of `speed` and the fact that `x_values_edited` is never closed make this unanswerable.

Comment: My speed is a list containing a list, it is a list of list @khelwood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick fix.

from matplotlib.pyplot import scatter, show, xlim, ylim

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import scatter, show, xlim, ylim

for index, item in enumerate(speed):
    scatter([times[index]]*len(item), item, marker='.')

xlim(min(times), max(times))
ylim(min(min(speed)), max(max(speed)))
show()
```

Produces:

[image]

Sorry it took long. I had to do it in the underground!

Comment: Really really thank you for your help :)  @PouriaHadjibagheri

Comment: Glad it helped... Thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. I had to generate the time since you haven't included the complete inputs in your question:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def date_range(stop, start, step=1):
    """
    Time generator
    :param stop: Stop time
    :type stop: Start time
    :param start: Steps based upon which the time is to be calculated.
    :type start: datetime.datetime()
    :param step: datetime.datetime()
    :type step: int, float
    """
    delta_date = stop - start
    numerator = 0

    while numerator < delta_date.seconds:
        yield start + timedelta(0, numerator)
        numerator += step

speed = [
    58.5, 97.0, 56.0, 87.5, 95.0, 100.0, 104.0, 
    98.5, 101.0, 98.5, 86.5, 90.0, 97.5, 16.5, 
    103.0, 98.0, 48.0, 98.5, 93.5, 99.0, 101.5, 
    86.5, 108.5, 22.0, 92.5, 84.5, 103.5, 86.5, 
    103.0, 96.5, 91.5, 101.5, 86.0
]


speed_len = len(speed)

# Hypothetical start time
date_start = datetime(2014, 3, 15, 0)
# and finish time
date_end = datetime(2014, 3, 15, 0, int(speed_len/60), speed_len%60)

# Generate a time list: 1 second per item in |speed|
x_values_edited = [val for val in date_range(stop=date_end, start=date_start, step=1)]

# Scatter plot
plot(x_values_edited, speed, '.')

# Display the plot
show()
```

Shows this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.    I have a list of speed values for each time points in date list (x_values_edited). With your solution, I am losing this point. I need to preserve the relation between speed and date.  @PouriaHadjibagheri

Comment: Of course you do. The point is, I needed the timesteps to calculate the scatter plot, and you had `........` at the end of it. Hence I generated another set. If you give me the exact inputs (within the next 20 minutes), I will give you a tailored solution.

Comment: Got it, you can delete that now before you someone removes the question.